# cannot download apps from play store

Tags: google-play-store

Previously my BSNL Penta T-Pad 701C was connected to the internet through a Beetel MF 190 3G USB dongle, but I could not download apps from Google Play. I contacted customer service who advised me to do a factory reset. After resetting my tab no longer connects to the net. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Factory resetting wipes the Wi-Fi settings along with everything else. From the Wi-Fi page in the **Settings** app, click on the network you want to connect to and enter the password (if it requires one), just as you did previously. If that doesn't work, update your question to say what happened.